# ChartJS Everything under one label?

Tags: .net-core, chart.js

I have to create doughnut chart with chartjs, and I had manage to create.
But there is small issue, under let's call content of chart I have different colors and data, but from main label from where should filter it I get all data under one label, why, what I did wrong ?
[image]

```
<script>


    var ctx = document.getElementById("racionMix").getContext('2d');
    var racionChart = new Chart(ctx,
        {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: [],

                datasets: [

                ]
            },
            // Configuration options go here
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        text: 'Racion Mix'
                    },
                }
            }
        });



    @for (int index = 0; index < @Model.Count; index++)
    {
        @:addData( "@Model[index].MixName", "@Model[index].TotalQty", getRandomColor())
    }

        function addData(label, value, color) {
            this.racionChart.data.labels.push(label);
            var newDataset = {
                label: label,
                backgroundColor: color,
                data: value,
            }
            this.racionChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
            this.racionChart.update();
        }


    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }




</script>
```

Also there one more think which is confusing me why I do not get chart
like here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/doughnut.html
On my chart seems like circle in circle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you make new datasets instead of adding to a dataset. Each dataset is its own circle. If you change your `addData` function and chart instantiation to the following it will work as expected:

```js
var racionChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'text that appears in the legend',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: []
        }]
    },
    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                fontSize: 16,
                text: 'Racion Mix'
            },
        }
    }
});

function addData(label, value, color) {
    this.racionChart.data.labels.push(label);
    this.racionChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(value);
    this.racionChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(color);
    this.racionChart.update();
}
```